# Java HotSpot VM Command-Line HeapDumpPath option use hostname for resulting .hprof

Tags: java

**Summary:** Id like to alter the way .hprofs are named when automatically created to incorporate machine's hostname + process PID

**Long version:** According to documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/clopts001.html) you can pass an option to the VM to create heapdumps under certain conditions (`HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`), and can further customize this behavior by specifying a different path for the resulting .hprof file. You can change the name/path. What I would like to know is if its possible to make this option (`HeapDumpPath`) incorporate the hostname+PID to have uniquely named .hprofs (to be saved in a centralized location, but thats another scope). Could it be done? Can `HeapDumpPath` accept a parameter to get the hostname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it just by using the Windows Environment Variable `COMPUTERNAME` in the wrapper.conf file for that particular Java VM. The full line is:

`wrapper.java.additional.32=-XX:HeapDumpPath=./%COMPUTERNAME%.hprof`

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there are options to inject values into the path. Depending on your shell you should be able to at least insert the hostname. The PID may not be possible since it is created after the process starts. You may be able to use a different variable like the application name though. In bash it would look something like this:

```
java -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -mn256m -mx512m ConsumeHeap -XX:HeapDumpPath=/disk2/dumps/$(hostname)/${APPLICATION_NAME}
```